# Speed up audio by time and not by percentage

Tags: ffmpeg, sox

Is it possible to speed up audio by time and not by percentage? I have thousands of audios and I need all of them to be 1 minute. I already searched but I haven't found anything. Thank you!

Comment: If you have thousands of them, you probably don't want to manipulate them one by one? Can't you just calculate the percentage?

Comment: FFmpeg doesn't seem to have much "speed it up based on the total length" so you can calculate total length (Ex: ffmpeg -i filename) and then "the percentage" you want and use that...